# Method of viewing both the contents of a Discord reply and the message replied to?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm new to Discord bot making, however I'm fairly familiar with commands such as on_message and have a simple bot running at the moment that gives movie recommendations from a list when asked.

In the event that the bot is replied to, is there any way for it to read what the reply says along with what the replied-to message says? I'm trying to set it up so that, if the bot suggests a movie and that message is replied to with a specific word, it will remove that movie from the list.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `['referenced_message']['content']`

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#messagereference in discord.py

Comment: I managed to get the message_id when replied to, however whenever I try to get the contents of the message via "await channel.fetch_message(message_id)" I get the message information rather than the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On discord.py, you can do
`referenced_message = original_msg.reference.resolved` for the message object itself, and then `referenced_message.content` to get the message's content from the object

Example code for your usage case:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    replied_to = True if message.reference is not None else False
    if replied_to:
        message_reference = message.reference.resolved
        original_msg_content = message_reference.content
        #do extra logic about the movie stuff and then send the message away
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you for the help, however when I attempt to integrate this code I get an "TypeError: 'Message' object is not subscriptable" error. I am using discord.py 1.7.3 as the bot is utilizing some other code that does not work past this version, if that may be causing an issue.

Comment: @Oyavo May I ask for the full traceback please?

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Oyavo/Desktop/bot/test.py", line 244, in on_message
    replied_to = True if message['reference']['resolved'] is not None else False
TypeError: 'Message' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Oyavo I've updated the code above to correct it, please try again now

Comment: Thank you! With the updated code I'm able to get the reply contents now. The only small issue however is that if a message is sent that isn't a reply to another, I get the following error: 

"replied_to = True if message.reference.resolved is not None else False
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resolved'"

Comment: I've updated the code again to account for that, please try again now

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: @Oyavo Glad I could help ya, please mark the answer as Accepted if it helped ya :)